# How do you make CSS Isolation work on referenced project?

Tags: css, razor, blazor, webassembly

I created a Razor library and then added a reference to the dll file from the Blazor WASM application. Adding the simple component1 into the index page won't bring the css in. It will work as expected when creating a new project within the solution and making a reference that way.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\ComponentLib\MyComponents.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ComponentLib">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\ComponentLib2\ComponentLib2\bin\Debug\net5.0\DeleteThisasap.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on the way around this?

Comment: Blazor css isolation is working in this way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 3):

Add the [projectname].styles.css in your index.html - where [projectname] is your main project. It builds on runtime as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

[image]

Actually when you browsed that [YourProjectName].styles.css,

You will see the bundled.scp.css from your referenced project that contains CSS Isolation

@import '_content/[ReferencedProjectName]/[ReferencedProjectName].bundle.scp.css';

Answer (score 0):

In your `wwwroot/index.html` add:

```
<link href="_content/YourComponentLib/YourComponentLib.bundle.scp.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, and managed to resolve it by publishing the Razor Component Library as a NuGet package. And then installing the Razor Library in the Blazor Server Side Application via the NuGet package manager. By doing this I didn't had to reference any stylesheets, automatically it added the "import" statement onto the Applications stylesheet.(as described in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#razor-class-library-rcl-support-1)